# Can't Set Progress Bar in Fresco

Tags: android, kotlin, fresco

I am reading the [documentation](http://frescolib.org/docs/using-simpledraweeview.html) for Fresco, and it says I can create a progress bar for a `SimpleDraweeView` with the following attribute:

```
fresco:progressBarImage="@drawable/progress_bar"
```

or with this code (I modified the example to work in Kotlin and work with a `draweeView` inside of a `recyclerview`)

```
val hierarchy : GenericDraweeHierarchy = GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder.newInstance(context.resources)
                                                    .setProgressBarImage(ProgressBarDrawable())
                                                    .build()

holder.draweeView.setHierarchy(hierarchy)
```

However, in my XML I am getting the "cannot resolve symbol" error in reference to the drawable.

Additionally, the `.setHierarchy(hierarchy)` is not recognized.

What's going on?

My `build.gradle` has the following dependencies (among others):

```
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.9.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.9.0'
```

Also, here is the XML layout for the item column for my `recyclerview`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
        android:id="@+id/itemImage"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.7"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        fresco:progressBarImage="@drawable/progress_bar"
        />


    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/itemFavoriteButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_favorite"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn=""
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/itemImage" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: show your `@drawable/progress_bar` xml

Comment: Oh, my bad, I was under the impression that adding Fresco to Gradle would automatically add "progress_bar" to my drawables. However, even if I manually have to create a progress bar drawable, that doesn't answer the question of why `.setHierarchy(hierarchy)` is not recognized.

Comment: I thought your question is *Can't Set Progress Bar in Fresco*. Also it is the cause, create a drawable or remove it and then try.

Comment: `.setHierarchy(hierarchy)` is a programmatic way to set the progress bar in Fresco. The fact that I can't set the `DraweeHierarchy` is worrying.